# (iOS) Send from signal extension to main target

Tags: ios, xcode-extension, xcode-target

I'm creating an application that monitors the usage time of applications on a device. I use DeviceActivity for this.
In DeviceActivityReportScene I receive the data DeviceActivityResults.
In DeviceActivityReportExtension I create a view (List) based on the received data.
And in the main application I call DeviceActivityReport(context:) to display it in the UIHostingController.

It all works. The question is this. By tapping on an element in the List, which is created in the DeviceActivityReportExtension extension, is it possible to transfer the selected element to the main application?
In other words, is it possible to receive callbacks from the extension (DeviceActivityReport) in the main application, through a delegate / closures or in another way?